# In-App Purchases - Keychain Access

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, keychain

My app currently uses the device's Keychain to determine if a user has unlocked/bought in-app purchases.

**Buy Item -> Store item password in keychain -> Unlock feature**

When the app loads, the Keychain is checked in order to determine what features have been unlocked. This all works perfectly, however I do have concerns regarding following scenario:

- **User** **A** unlocks/purchases all features on **device A**.
- **User A** uses his/her account to download app on **User B's** device (**device B**) and uses restore function.
- **Device B** can now be used by **User B** with all features unlocked on that device.

Obviously the above scenario highlights how one person could unlock features for another person, which is something that should be prevented.

How can this be overcome?

Comment: Is your user identified somehow? Login? Hash string?

Comment: I don't identify user logins no...

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't a way of overcoming this without authenticating the user somehow everytime the app loads? However, couldn't the user still use a different iTunes account to 'Restore' features, regardless of what user logs in to the app?

Comment: What if UserA will log into iTunes account which was used to buy items on UserB device, after restoring purchased items UserB logs and and also gets purchased items. So... I think you should somehow identify user... hash string for example of UUID or something like that.

Comment: Sorry but could you elaborate? Are you saying I should be using server-sided authentication? Or hash some UUID variable and store in locally and check against that each time or something?

Comment: I think if its critical to disallow userA to install purchased items on userB device - yes, server-side solution. UUID will not help, 'cause there will be no way to compare or to get information about userA who purchased items and userB which just used userA's account and restored that items.